# How can I get the value of conditioning variables being plotted in curent panel?

Tags: r, lattice

I have a dataframe, such as the one called dataset below, which has one column representing a factor, and two others representing values. I have also computed an average value for one of the columns per each level of the factor.

```
dataset <- data.frame(year=rep(1971:1977,3),
                      value=rnorm(21,160,6),
                      region=as.factor(c(rep("A",7),rep("B",7),rep("C",7))))
meancomp <-by(dataset$value,dataset$region,mean)
meanset <- data.frame(region=as.factor(c("A","B","C")),
meanvalue=c(meancomp[["A"]],meancomp[["B"]],meancomp[["C"]]))  

xyplot(value~year|region,
       data=dataset,
       panel=function(...) ({panel.xyplot(...}))
```

I would like to add to each panel a legend with the average value computed for that group. I would like to do so from inside the panel function specified (in the example code the panel just calls the default panel). I could of course pass the dataframe meanvalue to the panel, but, how can I know the value of the factor being ploted in each panel? (if I have that value, I can get the average from meanvale). Is there another, simpler way to achieve that same result?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Hi, I am not sure about the result you want, but it seems to me that you want to add the mean value in each panel, here it is : `dataset$MEAN <- ave(dataset$value, dataset$region )# computes the mean value and replicates it the number of time each region appears ;
xyplot(value+MEAN~year|region, type=c('l'), data=dataset,  auto.key = list( points = FALSE, lines = TRUE))`

Comment: I can do this, (though you are adding the mean to the graph, not putting it into a legend, it can be easily done). I can also do it using the subscripts variable and operating on the data.  But if I have 10 million records and five regions, it is a waste of space. I would like to be able to identify the value of the conditioning variables inside the panel function, it seems the proper way to do it, only  I do not know how.